# Hibernate collection not mapped - grails 2.2.4

Tags: hibernate, grails

This is on grails 2.2.4.

Given the following mapping:

```
class Store {
    static hasMany = [
       items : String
    ]
}
```

I would like to execute a search criteria for all store objects where it has items from a list.

So, I added this name query:

```
class Store {
    static hasMany = [
       items : String
    ]

    static namedQueries = {
        containsItem { itemIds ->
            'in' items, itemIds
         }
    }
}
```

However, I get an exception with the following error:

> 'collection was not an association'

A quick look online leads me to believe this is not implemented in the current Hibernate version... Annoyingly!

What are my options?

Thanks.

Comment: Please always say what Grails version. 2 or 3?

Comment: The Grails and Hibernate plugin versions would be helpful for individuals attempting to help you resolve your issue.